# Checking for a phrase within a string - Java

Tags: java, string, substring

```
String serverNamePercentage = "http://&askldjsakldjskadjlsajdklsajdlsjakldsjakldjsakl";
```

How do i check in that string that it starts with a "http://&"?

EDIT:

nevermind, i actually phrased my question wrongly. I wanted a method to check if the string contains "http://&" , not starts with it . i  just used

```
if ( myString.indexOf( "http://&" ) > -1 ) {
  //yes
 }
```

Comment: Your first place to check when dealing with String manipulation should always be the javadocs for the String class. :)

Comment: Seriously, reading the JavaDoc for `String` might be a good idea. The method is actually named `startsWith()`

Answer (score 3):

```
if(serverNamePercentage.startsWith("http://&")) {
   ...
}
```

Javadocs for [`String`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) are your friends. Here's the documentation for [`String#startsWith(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29).

**EDIT**

The reason you got downvoted on your question is because you didn't look up the Javadocs for `String` first. Your first step as a Java programmer should always be to look up the Javadocs. A quick google search would have also given you your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if (serverNamePercentage.startsWith("http://&")) {
    // yes, it does.
}
```